# nginx is refusing connection after root password change

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, root, digital-ocean

This is so strange. I am using digital ocean with serverpilot . I changed root password of the server and the site is down.

```
root@niche-hunter:/# sudo service nginx-sp restart
Job for nginx-sp.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx-sp.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@niche-hunter:/# journalctl -xe
-- Subject: Unit nginx-sp.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx-sp.service has begun starting up.
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter sshd[21087]: Failed password for root from 113.195.145.21 port 36880 ssh2
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter nginx[21115]: nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx-sp/certs/app.amzformula.com/yourdomain_com.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system l
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter nginx[21115]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx-sp/nginx.conf test failed
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter systemd[1]: nginx-sp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx-sp.
-- Subject: Unit nginx-sp.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx-sp.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter systemd[1]: nginx-sp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 19 14:22:27 niche-hunter systemd[1]: nginx-sp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 19 14:22:28 niche-hunter systemd[1]: nginx-sp.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 19 14:22:28 niche-hunter systemd[1]: Stopped nginx-sp.
-- Subject: Unit nginx-sp.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx-sp.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 19 14:22:28 niche-hunter systemd[1]: nginx-sp.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 19 14:22:28 niche-hunter systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx-sp.
-- Subject: Unit nginx-sp.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit nginx-sp.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 19 14:22:29 niche-hunter sshd[21087]: Failed password for root from 113.195.145.21 port 36880 ssh2
Aug 19 14:22:29 niche-hunter sshd[21087]: Received disconnect from 113.195.145.21 port 36880:11:  [preauth]
Aug 19 14:22:29 niche-hunter sshd[21087]: Disconnected from 113.195.145.21 port 36880 [preauth]
Aug 19 14:22:29 niche-hunter sshd[21087]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=113.195.145.21  user=root
Aug 19 14:22:29 niche-hunter sshd[21085]: Failed password for root from 221.194.47.233 port 33551 ssh2
Aug 19 14:22:30 niche-hunter sshd[21085]: Received disconnect from 221.194.47.233 port 33551:11:  [preauth]
Aug 19 14:22:30 niche-hunter sshd[21085]: Disconnected from 221.194.47.233 port 33551 [preauth]
Aug 19 14:22:30 niche-hunter sshd[21085]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=221.194.47.233  user=root
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way where root password change and nginx running state are correlated. Based on your logs, it seems you have an error in your config file.

Try running `nginx -t` and check what the error is.

According to the logs, it looks like you are missing a certificate at  `/etc/nginx-sp/certs/app.amzformula.com/your‌​domain_com.crt`

Comment: root@niche-hunter:/# nginx -t
The program 'nginx' can be found in the following packages:
 * nginx-core
 * nginx-extras
 * nginx-full
 * nginx-light
Try: apt install <selected package>
root@niche-hunter:/#

Comment: ok, you need to find your nginx executable. Maybe it is called `nginx-sp`?

Comment: root@niche-hunter:/# nginx-sp -t
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/nginx-sp/certs/app.amzformula.com/yourdomain_com.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/nginx-sp/certs/app.amzformula.com/yourdomain_com.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx-sp/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Looks like you are referencing to a certificate in `/etc/nginx-sp/certs/app.amzformula.com/your‌​domain_com.crt` but that file doesn't exist. Either remove it from the config file or ensure that file exists and contains the wanted certificate

Comment: did you solve the problem?